# Are uploads directories created on a schedule?

Tags: cron, wp-cron, uploads

I have a cron job that alerts me to modified files on a couple of WordPress installs.  Two of them alerted me tonight to the creation of apparently empty folders like

```
/home/foo/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/05
```

Is there a scheduled job in WordPress to create the next month's upload directory on the last day of a month?

Comment: I think these are created by user interaction and not automatically.

Comment: That's what I thought too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe by default these folders are created by user interaction, however, it's possible that a plugin may be calling a function to create these monthly upload folders.

> Note that using this function will create a subfolder in your Uploads folder corresponding to the queried month (or current month, if no $time argument is provided), if that folder is not already there. You don't have to upload anything in order for this folder to be created.

That's according to the the [Codex > Function Reference > `wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir). Maybe you could get more detailed logs to determine how they're created...I'm not real familiar with server administration.

Comment: +1, likely the reason. `wp_upload_dir()` can be used by many things to get information about paths and it does create those folders to have valid paths for current date.